# Error when i try to overview soap with php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

Hello i have some  request in soap but i have some error when i try the request in my website.

Fatal error: Call to a member function Body() on a non-object in /home/loraclec/public_html/pick5.php on line 14

Request :

```
<?php
/** define the SOAP client using the url for the service**/
$SoapiClient = new soapclient('http://14.141.212.201/ConRsltAPI/Result.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));
$lStrCred = "GI2304CON15";
$lStrGameName = "PICK3";
$lstrStatus = "0";
$thearray = array(
    'lStrCred' => $lStrCred,
    'lStrGameName' => $lStrGameName, 
    'lstrStatus' => $lstrStatus
);
$result = $client->Body($thearray);

if (is_soap_fault($result)):

    echo '<h1>ERRROR</h1><pre>';

    print_r($result);

    echo '</pre>';

else:

    echo '<h1>Working FINE</h1><pre>';

    print_r($result);

    echo '</pre>';

endif;

// see the last SOAP request
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest(), ENT_QUOTES);

// print the SOAP response
echo htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse(), ENT_QUOTES);

/** lets store the login token just in case we want to use it for later use**/

$token = $result->token;

?>
```

Comment: Try to change `$result = $client->Body($thearray);` with `$result = $client->ConAPI_RSLT($thearray);`

Comment: Should `$client` on line 14 not be `$SoapiClient`?

Answer (score 0):

`$client` doesn't exist on line 14. Change:

```
$result = $client->Body($thearray);
```

to

```
$result = $SoapiClient->Body($thearray);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answere, but i have another issue, when i  run the code i go back to the home page. the link --->  http://jeuxdufleuve.cd/pick3/pick3.php